# Chrome addon for Firefox search bar?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, search, search-engines

So in Firefox there's an address bar and a search bar right next to it.  I happen to have 12-15 different search engines (for various sites) on the search bar.

It's become a habit of mine to click on the search bar icon, hold down the mouse button and drag down until I get to the search engine I want and then let go of the mouse button and start typing my query.

Chrome has the unified bar which combines address and search bar.  I've imported the search engines into Chrome and I know I can type the name of site and press tab then it'll search with that search engine for the site.

I find it to be kinda troublesome to use (more typing) compared to what I was doing with the firefox search bar.  Any addon or tweaks to make it like firefox search?

Comment: Typing is actually faster than changing your hands from mouse to keyboard.

Comment: @dnbrv Actually no it's not.  I've have to type in the name of the search engine and depending on the name (how generic it is to a search term), I'd have to tab/arrow select the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Search Box](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mknehpjhljpfaghmicofickbkdagooni) for Chrome adds a secondary search box and allows you to import/use multiple search engines.